# Tridion Web 8.5: Can't copy and paste component

Tags: tridion

For some reason, I can't copy and paste component. I am getting an error saying "Unable to paste item, Automaton error". 
I am the system admin and this is really strange to me. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there's been a few issues related to the 'automation error' due to the missing msxml4 library.

https://gateway.sdl.com/articles/SolutionArticles/000002731

Comment: Thank you, John! We will verify this.

Comment: You're welcome, i hope it leads you down the right path.

Comment: Thanks, John. We are able to fix the issue by fixing the msxml4 library. .